# primefaces 3.2 bar chart x-axis value rendered incorrectly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, primefaces, managed-bean

i wish to display bar chart of primefaces but modified x-axis value, i wish to display years in the x-axis(dynamically) with following code but the years aren't displayed, instead i get the values such as 1,2,3... on x-axis for the years 2010,2011,2012,...:

managed bean:

```
    categoryModel = new CartesianChartModel();  
  objejb=(StockCommodityEJBStateless) new InitialContext().lookup("StockCommodityTest");
        ChartSeries scrip1 = new ChartSeries(); 
        scrip1.setLabel(scripSymbol1);  
        Collection coll=objejb.getScripQtyYearWise(scripID1);
        for (Object o : coll) {
        Object[] res = (Object[]) o;
        Number sum = (Number)res[0];
        Object year = res[1];
        scrip1.set(year,sum);
    }
        ChartSeries scrip2 = new ChartSeries(); 
        scrip2.setLabel(scripSymbol2);  
        Collection coll2=objejb.getScripQtyYearWise(scripID2);
        for (Object o : coll2) {
        Object[] res = (Object[]) o;
        Number sum = (Number)res[0];
        Object year = res[1].toString();
        scrip2.set(year,sum);
    }
categoryModel.addSeries(scrip1);
categoryModel.addSeries(scrip2);
```

where am i getting wrong? how do i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my mistake, i forgot to convert the object year to string!
just had to add for scrip1:

```
Object year = res[1].toString();
```